# Jquery selector using complete path

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through each section present under the anchor tag inside the first aside

```
<div id="85" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
   <div style="" class="Topping-details" id="85">
      <section id="topping_tsection_85">
         <aside>
            <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>

            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="85" topping_id="18"  topp_name="Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML" top_price="30" >Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>

            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="85" topping_id="19"  topp_name="Honey with Carmel  10 ML" top_price="30" >Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>

         </aside>
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is way i tried

```
$("#"+id+"' .activateUiHTML' #topping_tsection_"+id+" aside:first a").each(function(){
   var category=$(this).text();
   });
```

But i am getting error under console saying as undefined .

Could anybody please help me how to resolve this ??

Incase if i omit the `"#"+id+"' .activateUiHTML'`  then it is working fine . but i needed with this check also

Comment: Why the single quotes in `"#"+id+"' .activateUiHTML'`? Shouldn't it be `"#"+id+".activateUiHTML`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes and the space:

```
$("#"+id+".activateUiHTML #topping_tsection_"+id+" aside:first a").each(function(){
   var category=$(this).text();
   });
```

EDIT: As ruizfrontend pointed out, id's shoudn't start with numbers, but i don't think thats way it's not working. This is a validation thing and most browsers is forgiving about it. But it would be a good idea getting in the habit of not doing it though!

Answer (score 1):

There are two thing wrong.

- First you can't have a id starting with a number. http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/
- Second, there are two single quotes that shouldn't be there.
- Also there is a space between the id and his class that shouldn't be there

The final expression should be "#"+id+".activateUiHTML"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("div.activateUiHTML").find("aside").first("a").each(function(){
   var category=$(this).text();
   });
```